# Slide animation custom alert activity

Tags: android, android-animation

I have custom alert dialog as activity and I want to animate when the view appear and when exit, the first one works (when appear) but the second one doesn't work, I don't know how animate when exit (click outside) if someone can help me thank you in advance

```
public class CustomAlertActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.argb(200, 255, 0, 0)));

        ...

        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_down, R.anim.slide_in_out_up);
    }

}
```

slide_out_down.xml

```
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="1000" />"
    />
</set>
```

slide_in_out_up.xml

```
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="1000" />"
    />
</set>
```

manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".CustomAlertActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

[Custom alert activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubhya.png)

I also try this on MainActivity.class

```
  public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomAlertActivity.class);
                ActivityOptions options =
                        ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.slide_out_down, R.anim.slide_in_out_up);
                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
 }
```

**Solution:**

```
public class CustomAlertActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.argb(200, 255, 0, 0)));

            ...

        getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.CustomDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_down, R.anim.slide_in_out_up);
    }

}
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_out_down</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_in_up</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override finish of your activity and call the same method:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_down, R.anim.slide_in_out_up);
}
```

Comment: Glad I helped. Please accept the answer so others can find this easily!

Answer (score 0):

Add new style in styles.xml like this :

```
<style name="DialogTheme">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_out_down</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_in_out_up</item>
</style>
```

Then Call Animation on click Like This :

```
int style = R.style.DialogTheme
dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = style;
```

Hope So it will work if not please feel free to ask .

Comment: it works but I call "getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = style" in my CustomDialogActivity.class (inside onCreate(Bundle) method) and I don't why I have little flash before the second animation